# Data Annotation and EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, syncfusion

I working on wpf application with syncfusion datagrid (SfDataGrid). The grid uses a data-annotation for autogenerated columns. The model is prepared by EF6. I'm trying to set a column header. This code works (header showing):

```
    public partial class ViewShortConsumer
    {           
        [Display(Name = "Header of Column"]
        public string Firm { get; set; }
    }
```

But this - not work (header is default):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ViewShortConsumerMetadata))]
    public partial class ViewShortConsumer
    {             
        public string Firm { get; set; }     
    }


public class ViewShortConsumerMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Header of Column"]
    public string Firm;
}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are both classes in the same namespace?

Comment: yes. testing in one file and in same namespace